# How does firebase listen for changes in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, swift, firebase

I originally built my app in firebase but my app is scaling beyond its current capabilities very quickly. I am running into an issue with how to sync data such as firebase does. My plan is to make a call to a PHP script which interacts with my MySql database (switching to relational). Where I am lost is how to monitor changes to the database. The biggest draw for firebase is its real time capability for me. I want to receive changes when records are updated/removed/added/moved etc. What technologies are behind doing something like this and how to execute? MY app is built using Swift.

Comment: I suggest you do some research if you haven't already. Then, edit this question and include what you have tried and what has worked / not worked.

Comment: If you're just looking to broadcast changes that happen to your MySQL database, i'd look into triggers and socket.io. But to be honest, the scope is likely beyond what you can handle on your own and definitely way too broad for covering on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about this topic, but I think that building out your own realtime database it not an easy task. I would look into it some more online or use a service that offers that functionality. Might I ask why your app is going beyond the current capabilities? I am working on an app witth Firebase too.

Comment: Write now I am noticing problems with advanced search and authorization. I know some of the work arounds for advanced filtering in firebase are to concatenate data that you may want to search by but it's not very intuitive. Also creating sub users for an account is doable but not as sensible as something you could program custom.

Comment: I have a heavy amount of data where certain things should be available to certain users that belongs to another user but not to others. Very hard to work around this in a way that is very readable given the security available by firebase.